# json, Error converting value {null} to type 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, json, datetime, nullable

This JsonSerialization was thrown when I tried to input the following DateTime parameters in my Json:

```
string json = e.ExtraParams["Values"];
Dictionary<string, object>[] mats = JSON.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>[]>(json);
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Objects };
    ConcreteMat[] matList = JSON.Deserialize<ConcreteMat[]>(json, settings);
}
```

I tried Datetime? nullable it didnt work also i dont want to use nullable for my DateTime. Thank you for your attention

Related area in my ConcreteMat;
ConcreteMat;

```
DateTime processDate;

[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public DateTime ProcessDate
{
    get { return processDate; }
    set { processDate = value; }
}

  <DirectEvents>
        <Select OnEvent="ShowMatInfo">
              <ExtraParams>
                    <ext:Parameter Name="Values" Value="Ext.encode(#{grdMatList}.getRowsValues({selectedOnly:true}))"                                  Mode="Raw" />
                </ExtraParams>
         </Select>
  </DirectEvents>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where the json field is set? Also, the definition of ConcreteMat will probably be needed.

Comment: can you post the source data??

Comment: Where does json come from?

Comment: I assume your json doesn't contain the data for your date; in such case, you can't work around the issue, as your DateTime needs a value (because it is indeed not nullable). You need to use a nullable DateTime or provide the necessary value in the json.

Comment: I add my ConcreteMat related area @nikovn

Comment: thnk u @ Kilazur  but i tried to do my datetime are nullable than i got some exception

Comment: Ok, but please, add the area where the json is initialized. Do you get it from a web service call, do you initialize it yourself, etc?

Comment: I am initialize it myself @nikovn i edit it again.

Comment: I edit it @NicoRiff

Comment: The data you put is xml not showing how your json looks like. Also declare json serialization settings before deserialize logic and use it deserialize method.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thank you for your suggestion but i am not good json user so i dont clearly understand ur answer. Can u make ur answer clearly for me please?

Comment: Can you debug and see what value you are getting in json variable and share it here?

Comment: i am getting my DateTime area is null.